# Loading HTML from localStorage breaks function of a button

Tags: jquery, html

I save a part of my HTML (div class="savage") in **localStorage** and retrieve it when the page is refreshed. The HTML in question is a text-box for input with and "add new item" button and an unordered list of items with "delete" buttons and checkboxes. After I add a few items to my list and refresh the page, the list gets loaded correctly but I can't use the add button anymore. I can click on it but nothing happens and it won't append new items to the list. If anyone can tell me what I did wrong or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="savage">
   <h1>List of exercises to do today </h1>
   <h2> My workout <span id="counter"></span></h2>
       <form><input type="text" id="new-text"/></form><button id="add">Add</button>
           <ul id="mylist">
              <li> <input type="checkbox" class="done"/>figs<button    class="delete">delete</button></li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" class="done"/>pine nuts<button  class="delete">delete</button></li>
           </ul>
</div>
```

And **JQUERY**

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('peterslist')) {
    $('.savage').html(localStorage.getItem('peterslist'));
}
};

function updateStorage() {
    var peterslist = $('.savage').html();
    localStorage.setItem('peterslist', peterslist);
}
```

**BUTTON EVENT HANDLER**

```
$(function(){

  $("#add").on('click', addListItem);
  $(document).on('click', '.delete', deleteitem);
  $(document).on('click', '.done', finishItem);

});
```

Comment: Can you show us your button event handlers?

Comment: Added the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#add` is inside `.savage` which is changed therefore the handler linked to `#add` will be lost. As a result the following code

```
$(function(){

  $("#add").on('click', addListItem);
  $(document).on('click', '.delete', deleteitem);
  $(document).on('click', '.done', finishItem);

});
```

should be changed to this

```
$(function(){

  $(".savage").parent().on('click', "#add", addListItem);
  $(document).on('click', '.delete', deleteitem);
  $(document).on('click', '.done', finishItem);

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing the event handler fixed my issue! Follow-up question: could you please elaborate on the use of parent() in this particular case? Is it to traverse up one parent and then start searching for the #add from there?

Comment: @Max, you almost perfectly understood the idea. Basically we are searching for the first solid tag which contains savage. This is its parent. You correctly use .on() which applies to current and future elements matching the criteria of #add. So, it is searching for #add when you call the on(), but will apply to future instances of #add as well. If my answer solved your problem, you might consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: @LajosArpad Thank you for the explanation. And sorry, I tried to upvote it but it didn't let me because I'm new here. I accepted your solution!

Comment: @Max, I was happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the html content of `div.savage`, and, therefore, modifying the DOM. If you have events attached to your buttons, then those handlers may be outdated (using the old DOM nodes). Everytime you update the content of your `div.savage`, you should re-add your buttons callbacks:

```
window.onload = function() {
  if(localStorage.getItem('peterslist')) {
    // Changing the html will remove the old nodes, and, therefore, ignore old event handlers (click).
    $('.savage').html(localStorage.getItem('peterslist'));

    // Load again the `.click()` events here, after loading the html
    $("#add").on('click', addListItem);
    $(document).on('click', '.delete', deleteitem);
    $(document).on('click', '.done', finishItem);
  }
};
```

Comment: That is sub-optimal. The second and third click event handler will not disappear since they are linked to document.on(), while the first one is the problem. It can be linked to the parent of .savage, see my answer.