# Buttons retrieved from local storage not working

Tags: javascript, local-storage

So I'm a newb at web dev, and trying to get my head around JavaScript by writing a.. yeah, you guessed it, a to do list.

I've been trying to set the items to the local storage, and then retrieve it, it sorta works, however when the list items are retrieved, the buttons do not seem to function, and I can't for the life of me figure out why... Any thoughts?
Here's the code:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const submitButton = document.querySelector('.submit');
  submitButton.type = 'submit';
  const inputField = document.querySelector('.createItem');
  const toDoUl = document.querySelector('.toDoUl');
  const completedUl = document.querySelector('.completedUl');
  const form = document.querySelector('#header');
  const tdContainer = document.getElementById('tdContainer');
  const toDoItems = document.getElementById('toDoItems');
  (function loadStorage() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('todo')) {
      tdContainer.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('todo');
    }
  })();

  function noChildren() {
    if (toDoUl.hasChildNodes()) {
      tdContainer.classList.remove('tdContainer');
    } else {
      tdContainer.className = 'tdContainer';
    }
  }

  function createLi() {
    const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    const doneButton = document.createElement('input');
    const checkedLabel = document.createElement('label');
    doneButton.type = 'checkbox';
    checkedLabel.className = 'done';
    checkedLabel.appendChild(doneButton);
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    const editButton = document.createElement('button');
    const removeButton = document.createElement('button');

    toDoUl.appendChild(listItem);
    p.textContent = inputField.value;
    inputField.value = '';
    editButton.className = 'edit';
    removeButton.className = 'remove';
    listItem.appendChild(checkedLabel);
    listItem.appendChild(p);
    listItem.appendChild(editButton);
    listItem.appendChild(removeButton);
    doneButton.style.display = 'none';

    editButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      listItem.contentEditable = 'true';
    });

    listItem.addEventListener('blur', () => {
      listItem.contentEditable = 'false';
    });

    removeButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const ul = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
      /*const li = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;*/
      ul.removeChild(e.target.parentNode);
      noChildren();
    });

    doneButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className === 'toDoUl') {
        completedUl.appendChild(e.target.parentNode.parentNode);
        e.target.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'removeTransition';
        noChildren();
        localStorage.setItem('todo', tdContainer.innerHTML);
      } else {
        toDoUl.appendChild(e.target.parentNode.parentNode);
        e.target.parentNode.parentNode.className = 'addTransition';
        noChildren();
      }
    });
  }

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    noChildren();
    createLi();
    localStorage.setItem('todo', tdContainer.innerHTML);
  });
});
```

You can see the working version here: http://kozyrev.site/todo/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE here, not a link to a site that will no longer have the issue once you fixed it

Comment: You likely need to re-add the event listener when retrieving them. localStorage only stores STRINGS, so perhaps if you JSON.strigify and JSON.parse them, they might work again

Comment: Hello man. If you are starting dev to web a recomend you to look at some frameworks like [Vue JS](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/examples/todomvc.html).

Comment: For jQuery the issue is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043730/loading-html-from-localstorage-breaks-function-of-a-button

Comment: So I would use JSON.stringify, JSON.parse, and then add all the event handlers again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm glad you're writing arrow functions and cool stuff :D

but it seems that you are setting event listeners within `createLi` function, that is dispatched on form's `submit` event.

But, when you loads `localStorage`, is setting HTML content like this:

`tdContainer.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('todo');`

event listener is not attached to them, because all of these elements that you created from localStorage, is not create by `createLi` function :(

but you might write something like this:

```
// loads from localStorage
(function loadStorage() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('todo')) {
    tdContainer.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('todo');
  }
})();

// set listeners below
var liSelector = '.toDoUl > li'
var liElements = document.querySelectorAll(liSelector)

Array.prototype.forEach.call(liElements, (liElement) => {
  var editButton = liElement.querySelector('.edit')
  console.log(editButton)
  // you can set listeners here
  editButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('yey, event has dispatched, do your magic :)')
  })
})
```

---

**UPDATE: example using named function to reuse them:**

```
function createLi() {
....
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    ....
    editButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      listItem.contentEditable = 'true';
    });
```

could be written like this
    // this function at top of script
    const setEditable = (listItem) => {
      listItem.contentEditable = 'true';
    }

```
// you can use setEditable within createLi
function createLi() {
....
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    ....
    editButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      setEditable(listItem)
    });
```

also, after HTML was written from localStorage like this

```
// loads from localStorage
(function loadStorage() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('todo')) {
    tdContainer.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('todo');
  }
})();

// set listeners below
var liSelector = '.toDoUl > li'
var liElements = document.querySelectorAll(liSelector)

Array.prototype.forEach.call(liElements, (listItem) => {
  var editButton = listItem.querySelector('.edit')
  // you can set listeners here
  editButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    setEditable(listItem)
  })
})
```

**I didn't tested**, but i hope it works, and it's shows you that named function could be reused for setting listeners :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm working on it now to implement your idea, strugling a litle, but at least the buttons are responsive! Thanks again!

Comment: Good luck :D, most part of logic is is written within `createLi` function, if you write named function, you could use these named function for attaching event, i will update my answer with example.